How to Recognize Chessboard Corners with OpenCV from Side View Image with Pieces on Board?
I'm using OpenCV for chessboard corner detection from a side-view image where pieces are present on the board. I've processed the image through several steps including grayscale conversion, Gaussian blur, thresholding, morphology, dilation, and Canny edge detection, but I'm struggling to accurately identify the chessboard corners.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load and preprocess the image
img = cv.imread("input.jpg")
img = cv.resize(img, (1280, 720))
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
opening = cv.morphologyEx(gray, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
dilation = cv.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=1)
canny = cv.Canny(dilation, 100, 200)

# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
if contours:
    largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv.contourArea)
    cv.drawContours(img, [largest_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=cv.FILLED)
    rect = cv.minAreaRect(largest_contour)
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int32(box)
    cv.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Show image
cv.imshow("Image", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()


What adjustments can I make to improve contour detection for the chessboard?
Here is are input and output images: https://imgur.com/a/o7GkRQb

I also tried using some post such as

How to find corners on a Image using OpenCv

OpenCV C++/Obj-C: Advanced square detection


for help. But It didn't really work.

Are there any other types of images that you would like to handle? Or is the sample image representative of all your inputs?
